Does macOS Time Machine backup passwords stored in Keychain Access application?
I am wondering if macOS Time Machine backs up passwords stored in Keychain Access application.

Yes - it does backup keychains.

Passwords are inside keychains. They are stored here ~/Library/Keychains and are backed up by Time Machine.
You can check by looking in your TM backup using Finder and going to <TMdisk>/<date-time>/<boot disk> - Data/Users/<user>/Library/Keychains/
